# Change app background

Tags: java, android, background, settings

I'm currently making an android app in which I'd like the user to be able to change the background image.
I've got 3 images and a screen where I can choose a picture and a button for applying.

**The issue:** 
I can allow the user to see all images in the way I want, but I don't know how to set the selected image as app background.

**What I want to do:** 
I want the user to click a button, which exports the selected image to "bakgrund.png" in "/res/drawable-mdpi" and replaces the current one. This would allow me to easily integrate the background switcher. Renaming of current files also works.

**PS:** My current background images are located in /res/drawable-mdpi named 1.png 2.png and 3.png.

Comment: What exactly is the question? It seems you are asking us to design the entire thing for you.

Comment: can you post your main.xml or whatever xml file you are calling in setContentView(...) in the onCreate of your activity?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Easiest way would be to call the `setBackgroundResource(image_id)` method on the root layout. Like if you have a `LinearLayout` which has `android:id="@+linear"` as the root layout in the layout xml, then this code will help:-

```
LinearLayout linearLayout=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear);
linear.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.1);//call this in the OnClickListener's OnClick Method
```

Comment: I like the code implementation, and got it working, but only on the current view. Also, as soon as I leave the window the drawable returns to it's old state (1.png). Is there a way to make this setting apply for all Relative Layouts named might and keep the setting, even when restarting the whole app?

Comment: You can't give same id to more than one view, or else you might get a ClassCastException. Instead you can have those layouts' objects in an ArrayList and then in the OnClick() method of Button's listener you can run a loop on the ArrayList to set the background of every layout to the desired drawable.

Comment: Ok... Here's what I got out of that: I cannot have the same id on the RelativeLayouts?

And still there's the problem of keeping the image when activity gets destroyed and applying for all layout xml's. I read about doing it with shared content view or strings, but I just couldn't get it to work.
thx for helping me. :)

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you need different themes which has different backgrounds. So you may use `this.setTheme` method in your `Activity`.

Indeed I suggest you, two different **layout** (with different backgrounds but have same components) and using `setContentView` during `onClick`.

I hope it solves your issue.